# Using Tikz in tufte_handout with RMarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, tikz

I am trying to generate a tikz figure in R Markdown using the `tufte_handout` I am running this in RStudio. Here is my `sessionInfo()`:

```
    R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
    Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0 (64-bit)
    Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.2

    locale:
    [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
     [1] backports_1.0.4 magrittr_1.5    tufte_0.2       rprojroot_1.1   htmltools_0.3.5 tools_3.3.2     yaml_2.1.14     Rcpp_0.12.8    
     [9] stringi_1.1.2   rmarkdown_1.3   knitr_1.15.1    stringr_1.1.0   digest_0.6.11   evaluate_0.10
```

My example (not working yet) is:

````
     ---
     title: "TikzTest"
     output: 
       tufte::tufte_handout: default
     ---

     This is a test of the R Markdown tufte_handout.^[This is a sidenote in the tufte_handout] To use the tikz package, you have to include this code chunk:
     ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
     knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,dev = 'tikz')
     library(tikzDevice)
     ```

     But it doesn't work?:
     ```{r,engine='tikz'}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.05cm]

     \node [align=center] (x) at (0,0) {$X$};
     \node [align=center] (y) at (2.55,0) {$Y$};

     \begin{scope}[line width=.05cm,shorten >= 5pt, shorten <= 5pt]
     \draw[->,color=black] (x) to (y);
     \end{scope}
     \end{tikzpicture}
     ```
````

When I knit this, I get the following error:

```
     Error in tools::texi2dvi(texf, pdf = !to_svg, clean = TRUE) : 
       Running 'texi2dvi' on './tikz145322b8f468.tex' failed.
     Messages:
     sh: /usr/local/opt/texinfo/bin/texi2dvi: No such file or directory
     Calls: <Anonymous> ... call_block -> block_exec -> in_dir -> engine -> <Anonymous>
     Execution halted
```

I have the MacTeX-2016 Distribution installed

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Mac, but I was receiving the same error that you were while running the code you provided. To fix it, all I had to do was take this line:

`line:knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,dev = 'tikz')`

and change it to the following:

`knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)`

With that change, it worked just fine with what I imagine is the output you're looking for. Hopefully, this will work on a Mac as well.

Comment: Thanks, but no luck. I still get the same error, even when I remove `dev = 'tikz'` from the chunk_set option.